# How to solve "Both use the XML type name X, use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type"?

Tags: c#, serialization, attributes

I have the following enum definitions...

```
namespace ItemTable
{
  public enum DisplayMode
  {
    Tiles,
    Default
  }
}

namespace EffectiveItemPermissionTable
{
  public enum DisplayMode
  {
    Tree,
    FullPaths
  }
}
```

...and then i have the following classes...

```
public class Table<TDisplayMode>
  where TDisplayMode: struct
{
  // public
    public TDisplayMode DisplayMode
    { 
      get { return mDisplayMode; }
      set { mDisplayMode = value; }
    }

  // private
    private TDisplayMode mDisplayMode;
}

public class ItemTable : Table<ItemTable.DisplayMode>
{}

public class EffectiveItemPermissionTable : Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode>
{}

public class UISettings
{
  public UISettings()
  {
    ItemTable = new ItemTable();
    EffectiveItemPermissionTable = new EffectiveItemPermissionTable();
  }

  public ItemTable ItemTable { get; set; }
  public EffectiveItemPermissionTable EffectiveItemPermissionTable { get; set; }
}
```

...and when i try to serialize an instance of UISettings with...

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer lSerializer =
  new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(UISettings));
```

...i get the following error:

```
Types 'UISettings.Table`1[EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode]' and
'UISettings.Table`1[ItemTable.DisplayMode]' both use the XML type name,
'TableOfDisplayMode', from namespace ''.

Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.
```

I have tried to use XmlType attribubtes and all sorts of solutions posted on the web but nothing works. The XML type name is always `TableOfDisplayMode` as mentioned in the error.

The only solution right now is to rename one of the enums, e.g. to `DisplayMode_` but I find that rather ugly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the [Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.namespace(v=vs.110).aspx) by using the `XmlElement` attribute on the properties of your `UISettings` class:

```
public class UISettings
{
    public UISettings()
    {
        ItemTable = new ItemTable();
        EffectiveItemPermissionTable = new EffectiveItemPermissionTable();
    }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "Item")]
    public ItemTable ItemTable { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "Permissions")]
    public EffectiveItemPermissionTable EffectiveItemPermissionTable { get; set; }
}
```

When applied here this will be your serialized output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UISettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
   <ItemTable xmlns="Item">    
      <DisplayMode>Tiles</DisplayMode>  
   </ItemTable>  
   <EffectiveItemPermissionTable xmlns="Permissions">    
       <DisplayMode>FullPaths</DisplayMode>  
   </EffectiveItemPermissionTable>
</UISettings>
```

Alternatively, and maybe cleaner, you can provide the Namespace on the types:

```
[XmlType(Namespace="Item")]
public class ItemTable : Table<ItemTableNS.DisplayMode>
{ }

[XmlType(Namespace = "Permission")]
public class EffectiveItemPermissionTable : Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTableNS.DisplayMode>
{ }
```

This will serialize as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<UISettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ItemTable>
    <DisplayMode xmlns="Item">Tiles</DisplayMode>
  </ItemTable>
  <EffectiveItemPermissionTable>
    <DisplayMode xmlns="Permission">FullPaths</DisplayMode>
  </EffectiveItemPermissionTable>
</UISettings>
```

Comment: Oh my...works! Thx. But why do i need to specify a namespace? Why doesn't the serializer just use the property name as namespace?

Comment: Well, the serializer doesn't use namespaces by default and generating them when needed would probably break more scenario's. Namespaces are in that sense similar to namespaces in c#. it does matter if `Label` is coming from the System.Windows.Forms or System.Web.WebControls namespace.

Comment: Ok, but why is it even necessary to add a `xmlns` attribute to the DisplayMode nodes? Any specific reason?

Comment: Because without it the deserializer can't possible know which DisplayMode  belonging to one of those types the given element relates to.

Comment: But why? I don't had a look at the source code of the deserializer but i assume it has the meta info from the classes and the classes each have a property DisplayMode and each property has a type that itself provides also meta info. Therefore everything is available to deserialize it. Hmm perhaps i have to live with that attribute. Very strange...

Answer (score 13):

I realize this answer probably comes way too late for the OP, but there is a way to do this without using namespaces, so I'm going to leave an answer here in case somebody comes along after me and needs the solution.

The problem is caused by the fact that the way the `XmlSerializer` names a type `X<Y>` is by giving it the name `XOfY`. Thus, when you have two types that both derive from `Table<TDisplayMode>`, you get that error, since they'll both be known internally as `TableOfDisplayMode`, despite actually using different enums.

This is because `ItemTable` and `EffectiveItemPermissionTable`are actually **not** inheriting from the same type! One inherits from `Table<ItemTable.DisplayMode>` and the other from `Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode>`. Not that this is limited to inheritance; you'd face the same problem if you tried to use them directly in the same XML object graph also.

Now, for the non-generic counterpart to this problem, you'd just smack an `[XmlType]` on the two types, and call it a day. But you can't do that here. While `Table<ItemTable.DisplayMode>` and `Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode>` are different types, they share the same class definition, so by trying to use `[XmlType]`, you're giving them a different name, but still the same name.

So what can you do? `XmlAttributeOverrides` to the rescue! It lets you override the names the `XmlSerializer` gives to closed generic types, meaning that you can finally give a different name to `Table<ItemTable.DisplayMode>` and `Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode>`:

```
var xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

var xmlAttribs = new XmlAttributes();   
xmlAttribs.XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute("TableOfItemTableDisplayMode");
xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(Table<ItemTable.DisplayMode>), xmlAttribs);

xmlAttribs = new XmlAttributes();
xmlAttribs.XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute("TableOfEffectiveItemPermissionTableDisplayMode");
xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(Table<EffectiveItemPermissionTable.DisplayMode>), xmlAttribs);

var lSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(UISettings), xmlOverrides);
```

And voilà! Assuming now that you've also put `[XmlType]` with different names for your `DisplayMode` enums, so that their names don't conflict either, you've got yourself a working setup!