# How to fix XML serialization issues in ASMX web service

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization, asmx

We have an asmx web service A which is consuming a WCF service B with below DataContract structure.

```
[DataContract]
public class Animal
{
    [DataMember]
    string AnimalName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    Head[] head { get; set; }

}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    string PersonName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    Head[] head { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Head
{
    [DataMember]
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

We are receiving below error while running an asmx web service A.

Types 'Animal.Head' and 'Person.Head' both use the XML type name, 'Head', from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

We also tried putting a different XMLElement namespace in DataContract but didn't help.

```
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:/A/Animal/")]
    [DataMember]
    Head[] head { get; set; }
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Both use the XML type name X, use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762480/how-to-solve-both-use-the-xml-type-name-x-use-xml-attributes-to-specify-a-uniq)

Comment: Does it work with no namespace?  Try [XmlElement("Head")] or leave out completely.

Answer (score 0):

XmlElement is used for XmlSerializer, wcf by default uses DataContractSerializer to 
serialize and deserialize model.

If you want to use XmlSerializer , you could refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class

DataContract also has a Namespace property which could specify namespace for your model.